# pydelicious.get_popular('programming') doesn't return any valid url

Tags: python

I'm learning **Collective intelligence programming** in python. When I tried to repeat the pydelicious related codes, I found that `pydelicious.get_popular('programming')` didn't return any valid urls. The result was `{'extended': '', 'description': u'something went wrong', 'tags': '', 'url': '', 'user': '', 'dt': ''}`. So you can see that where is supposed to be some url is empty (`''`) and the description is `something went wrong`. I've installed the `pydelicious` using `sudo easy_install` with `setup.py` downloaded from `google code`. And I can successfully import `pydelicious` module. I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
from pydelicious import get_popular,get_userposts,get_urlposts

def initializeUserDict(tag,count=5):
    user_dict={}
    # get the top count popular posts
    for p1 in get_popular(tag=tag)[0:count]:
        # find all users who posted this
        print p1
        for p2 in get_urlposts(p1['url']):
            user=p2['user']
            user_dict[user]={}
    return user_dict

user_dict=initializeUserDict('programming')
print user_dict
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the Delicious API itself:
http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/popular/starwars

Looking into the [API documentation](https://delicious.com/rss), it looks that this is no longer supported. But if you test if the 'recent' tags, it fails as well.

I sent them an email about this possible bug, lets see...

Answer (score 2):

You should modify the`__init__.py` to:

```
rss = http_request('http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss').read()
```

I see the resource code again.
Maybe it is wrong.Because If you edit the code,the procedural answer always remain unchanged...I'm studing...

Comment: You are right. I'm Chinese ^_^ Thank you for the answer. I guess it is a good idea to skip that part for now, before a solution is found for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is from d.hatena.ne.jp/seika_m/20150910:

I fixed 2 line of "pydelicious.py".

```
DLCS_RSS = 'http://del.icio.us/rss/'
```

to

```
DLCS_RSS = 'http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/'
```

and

```
def get_popular(tag = ""):
  return getrss(tag = tag, popular = 1)
```

to

```
def get_popular(tag = ""):
  return getrss(tag = tag, popular = 0)
```

The problem was solved.

Indeed. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

make changes to **init**.py

replace

```
elif popular == 0 and tag != '':
    # http://del.icio.us/rss/tag/apple
    # http://del.icio.us/rss/tag/web2.0
    url = DLCS_RSS + "tag/%s" % tag

elif popular == 1 and tag == '':
    url = DLCS_RSS + 'popular/'

elif popular == 1 and tag != '':
    url = DLCS_RSS + 'popular/%s' % tag
```

with

```
elif popular == 0 and tag != '':
        # http://del.icio.us/rss/tag/apple
        # http://del.icio.us/rss/tag/web2.0
        url = DLCS_RSS + "%s" % tag

    elif popular == 1 and tag == '':
        url = DLCS_RSS + 'popular/'

    elif popular == 1 and tag != '':
        url = DLCS_RSS + '%s' % tag
```